# how to convert type'string' into system.drawing.image

Tags: c#, database, c#-3.0

I just want to get the image from database into a picture box as like other data is. How can I do that?

```
private void dataGridView1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
      //shows the data on fields if click on the entries 
      //on sequence in which the query is 

      IDtxt.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
      NAMEtxt.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
      F_Nametxt.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
      BLOODc_box .Text  = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
      CNICtxt .Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
            
      GENDERc_box .Text  = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
      CONTACTtxt.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[6].Value.ToString();
      JOBtitleText.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[7].Value.ToString();
      SALARYtxt.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[8].Value.ToString();
      ADDRESStxt.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[9].Value.ToString();
      AGEtxt .Text  = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[10].Value.ToString();
      pictureBox1 .Image   =  dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[11].Value.ToString();

}
```

Comment: pictureBox1 .Image   =  dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[11].Value.ToString();

this line generates error tht "cannot convert type'string into system,drawing,image'"

Comment: `dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[11].Value` contains type string or bytes?

Comment: a string cannot be turned into an image - it can be written on an image, but not just made an image. Just like you cant hang a .jpg on your wall, it might contain the picture you want, but you have to do things to turn it into something you can put on a wall

Answer (score 2):

If you have base64 string then try this

```
var image = GetImage("yourBase64String");

public Image GetImage(string value)
{        
    byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(value);
    Image image;
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
    {
        image = Image.FromStream(ms);
    }
    return image;
}
```

Comment: i tried ,but this didn't work properly .Basically what i want is to show the image in picture box from dataGridView1 
im getting all the data in corresponding textboxes when i click on grid row  (like ID,NAME,FATHER_NAME etc) but i failed to show the image in text boxe..... i want to show the data in all textboxes and image in picture box ... :(

Comment: Did you try this `pictureBox1.Image = GetImage(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[11].Value.ToString().Trim());`?

Comment: Can you show string containing by `dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[11].Value.ToString()`?

Comment: pictureBox1.Image = GetImage(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[11].Value.ToString().Trim());

this is not working

Comment: finally i retrieved image from the database by clicking in datagridview by this line of code
 byte[] img = (byte[])dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[11].Value;
              if (img == null)
              {
                  pictureBox1.Image = null;
              }
              else
              {
                  MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(img);
                  pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
              }
but now having another prob which is , my code didnt save the data if i didnt upload the image . i want to leave this optional whether someone want to upload or not

Comment: private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)  // ADD the data to database
        {
           byte[] imagebt = null;    // will hold the pic 
            FileStream fstream = new FileStream(this.textBox_image_Path.Text, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fstream);
            imagebt = br.ReadBytes((int)fstream.Length);

generating EXception in 2nd line that  ,Additional information: Empty path name is not legal.

Comment: private void button1_Click_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
            dlg.Filter = "JPG Files(*.jpg)|*.jpg|PNG Files(*.png)|*.png|ALL File(*.*)|*.*";



            if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                                          {
                string picpath = dlg.FileName.ToString(); 
                textBox_image_Path.Text = picpath;
                pictureBox1.ImageLocation = picpath ;

Comment: Do you want to save image?

Comment: Why are you not using `Image.Save` Method?

Comment: because i have to save every type of images like .jpg ,PNG etc

Comment: So use this as `Image.Save("D:\images\image1.jpg");` for JPEG and `Image.Save("D:\images\image2.png");` for PNG

Answer (score 0):

```vb
'Picture 
Dim myFile As String = gvAutok.SelectedRows(0).Cells(9).Value
Dim Image As Image = Image.FromFile(myFile)
picBox.Image = Image
```